# Search emails by subject using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

All,

I'm stuck at the following. I get list of emails in my inbox, and I need to search emails that contain specific string in subject (and then parse body of that email). I'm stuck at getting right syntax for filtering emails by subject.
I have this:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$emails = $inbox.items
$subjectComparisonExpression = "Meeting topic is: "
```

But then none of these work:

```
#1
$inbox.items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like $subjectComparisonExpression} | Write-Host($_.Subject)

#2
$myemails = $inbox.items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like $subjectComparisonExpression}
Write-Host($myemails.count)

#3
$myemails = $emails | Where {$_.Subject -like $subjectComparisonExpression} 
Write-Host($myemails.count)
```

How do I get list of emails where subject contains `$subjectComparisonExpression`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to find items that correspond to your conditions. The `Restrict` method is an alternative to using the `Find` method or `FindNext` method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found. You can read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thanks! It is not immediately obvious how to use it with Subject where I need to exactly match only portion of the subject ( Like CONTAINS). It's not ```[Subject] = partialmatch```?

Comment: You can use `like` as well for the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison

Comment: Well, 'like' did not work. Said "Condition is not valid". I tried it as `$emails.Restrict("[subject] like '%topic is%'")`. What did work was  `$emails.Restrict("@SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" ci_phrasematch 'topic is'")`

Comment: Only in the code needed to escape double quotes for "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with '-like' keyword. Replaced it with '-match' and it works.